# Pi Zero W Wifi and SSH turning off

Tags: pi-zero-w

I have several Pi Zero W all with the latest Rasbian, running headless.  After a few hours I lose the ability to contact them via WiFi or SSH, they are however still running as logs show.  Basically I have to reboot them at the power plug.  I have swapped SD cards around and power adaptors - I'm sure it's a software setting

I have edited   /etc/network/interfaces to include the line 
wireless-power off and iwconfig | grep "Power Management" shows  “Power Management:off”  but this has no effect

If its any help I am running them on static IP 
sudo nano /etc/dhcpcd.conf

interface wlan0

static ip_address=192.168.0.xxx/24
static routers=192.168.0.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.0.1

Any help gratefully received. Thanks

===

Rubberstamp  - Thanks for the help:  with journalctl  I get  ***No journal files were found.*** 
 I can see results in cat /var/log/auth.log  (but i have no idea what to look for) and systemctl status dhcpcd (the unit has not shut off reads

dhcpcd.service - dhcpcd on all interfaces
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dhcpcd.service; enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2017-11-26 18:57:12 GMT; 1h 38min ago
  Process: 371 ExecStart=/sbin/dhcpcd -q -b (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 382 (dhcpcd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/dhcpcd.service
           └─382 /sbin/dhcpcd -q -b**.

I'm afraid this is all a bit above my pay grade, so thanks for bearing with me

Comment: What is the output of: `journalctl -u ssh --since YYYY-MM-DD` and `journalctl -u dhcpcd --since YYYY-MM-DD`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problems.

Here is what I fond out and how I worked around the loss  of wifi

1. Create errors `touch /home/pi/errors`
2. Create `/home/pi/resetwifi.sh`

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   ping -c1 "yourroutersip"
   if [ $? != 0 ]
   then
     sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
     date >> /home/pi/errors  
     sleep 5
     sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
   fi
   ```
3. Add entry to run every 5 min in crontab

   ```
   crontab -e 
   5 * * * * /home/pi/resetwifi.sh
   ```

The errors file shows that my wlan0 is shutting down every hour. I don't know why

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem with rpi0w, it was losing wifi every 2 hours or so. I figured out that the problem was DHCP by looking in the /var/log/syslog, I disabled dhcpd and enabled network interfaces in rpi0w and it has never lost wifi since then. I followed the answer [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37920/how-do-i-set-up-networking-wifi-static-ip-address-on-raspbian-raspberry-pi-os/74428#74428) to configure this and basically involves two steps:

1. Configure a static network adddress on your Pi in /etc/network/interfaces
2. Disable the DHCP client daemon and switch to standard Debian networking

Comment: Could you add the section in /var/log/syslog/ that lead you to the conclusion?

Comment: It was similar to this [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=1533060)